# Cannot open Native Access with Wine

Tags: wine

I've been having a very hard time installing Native Access through Wine.
I'm running Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon with Windows 7 on Wine configuration.
If I try to run the .exe with `wine Native-Access_2.exe` I get the installation window open up, load for a couple seconds the I get this error and the installation window closes -> [error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4m4H.png)
I then click OK and get this on the terminal

```
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread 1dc at address 00000001416E0048 (thread 01dc), starting debugger...
```

I then wait for like 5 minutes for a 'debugger' to do something, but nothing happens...
I searched already a lot online but I can't find anything similar for some reasons.

Comment: what is "Native Access"? Some kind of driver framework? Could you link to a description of that software? If it is some driver framework, does it not really need the actual windows operating system kernel to work?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a platform to install audio softwares and VSTs [link](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/specials/native-access-2/)

Comment: I think I bumped into a game that would trigger something similar if wine cannot reach the sound server (pulse). Make sure you have the 32-bit libpulse and so installed, and that the pulse server is running and reachable.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2 of Native Access is an Electron application that uses an API to call a UAC prompt that is not yet supported in Wine. The current workaround is to install the legacy, Qt-based Native Access (version 1), which as of 20 Nov 2022 is available [here](https://support.native-instruments.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000407909-Native-Access-1-Legacy-Installers-for-Older-Operating-Systems). One hopes that Native Instruments will continue to support this older version.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the old version.  I'm installing it now.  Its not like Electron apps can't run on Linux ...

Comment: On my system, the 1.14.1 installer hangs on the "Installing the Native Instruments ISO Driver" section. However, if you kill the installer it does look like Native Access installed. However I'm getting the same issue as this gentlemen here when it runs: https://www.native-instruments.com/forum/threads/running-via-wine-on-linux-systems.373433/
Namely that it thinks its a mac and provides instructions to put the app into the "Applications" folder. The solution there was to use wine staging, but at the time that was 5.x. We are on 7.x.

Comment: Sorry to spam the comments, but it looks like I was trying to run it without setting the prefix that I created with winetricks.  If you don't create a new prefix, this should still work with stock wine 7.x.

Comment: What Bottles/Wine settings and dependencies do you need to get the 1.14 installer to work please? Mine either crashes or gives black screen when using the standard FL Studio Bottle, for which Spitfire and other VSTs work fine.

Comment: @Richard, I have Spitfire and Native Access 1 working with the latest wine-staging (8.19-1 in Manjaro). For the Spitfire LABS manager, I had to install it into a separate wine prefix where I had installed [dxvk](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk). For many recent apps and plugins, dxvk is necessary to get the plugins to redraw, otherwise the plugin screen freezes and redraws only when moving the plugin window or closing/reopening it. I don't think Native Instruments stuff requires dxvk yet. I'd put install stuff plugin family (NI, Spitfire, Plugin Alliance, etc.) into their own wine prefixes.